# html agility pack and triangular brackets in text

Tags: html-agility-pack

When I load certain html files with Html Agility Pack, I get that it will not close some tags (looking at InnerHtml and OuterHtml properties) when text within html tags has triangualr braces like this

```
<span class='title'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Launching app results in an error "Activation of http://<server name="">/TemplateBuilder/?language=1033&locale=1033 resulted in exception"</span>
```

so as output I get

```
<span class='title'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Launching app results in an error "Activation of http://<server name="">/TemplateBuilder/?language=1033&locale=1033 resulted in exception"
```

Is there anything that can be done to preserve it?  Because  is missing on output, the whole html is not displayed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your original html is too invalid. It should be:

```
<span class='title'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Launching app results in an error "Activation of http://&lt;server name=""&gt;/TemplateBuilder/?language=1033&locale=1033 resulted in exception"</span>
```

This kind of malformed html cannot be detected by the Html Agility Pack.

Comment: I don't have control over how input html is formed.  However they are displayed in a browser just fine before being processed by the Html Agility Pack.

Comment: I am having the same issue, I have no control over how the HTML given to me is formed but angle brackets appear in free text and HTML Agility Pack refuses to process html at all. It just chucks it out. No idea what to do about this.